# [ros2 humble]build error in pcl_conversions.h:fatal error: No such file message_event.h

Tags: ros2, pcl-conversions

my test code include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>, build will report can't find message_event.h(the file included by pcl_conversions.h). i found the file message_event.h exist and its path is /opt/ros/humble/include/message_filters/message_filters/message_event.h, but pcl_conversions.h include it using <message_filters/message_event.h>, this include path may be not correct, should be <message_filters/message_filters/message_event.h>?
but in ros2 eloquent, the path of message_event.h included by pcl_conversions.h correspond to the path /opt/ros/eloquent/include/message_filters/message_event.h.

my platform is Ubuntu22.04 and the ros-humble-pcl-conversions installed by `apt-get install ros-humble-pcl-conversions`, the current PCL version is 1.12

whether anyone meet the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it seems my CMakeLists.txt cause the issue, i added the following about "pcl_conversions" additionally

```
find_package(pcl_conversions REQUIRED PATHs /opt/ros/humble)

ament_target_dependencies(
...
"pcl_conversions"
)
```

the issue is disappeared, but it confused me at the same time, in ros2 eloquent, i didn't add those in my CMakeLists.txt and it finished build without any error.